# How can generate unique auto incremement formatted number using php

Tags: php

I have a loan application form and it has application No field. it should be readonly. Now i want to generate auto increment formatted number and show inside my text box. application No should be like "LN/SS-DATE-000". can anyone explain, How to generate this number using php and echo in my text box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a unique auto increment number, then you need to store the last generated number somewhere. If you use a database, then the easiest is to store it in a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `counter` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `stub` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `stub` (`stub`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

Use the following queries to increase the counter and get the actual value:

```
REPLACE INTO `counter` (`stub`) VALUES ('a');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

You can read more about this technique on Flickr's [blog](http://code.flickr.net/2010/02/08/ticket-servers-distributed-unique-primary-keys-on-the-cheap/).